# Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Build

Tags: dynamic, jenkins, groovy, parameters, build

I am new to Jenkins and I am looking to create a parameter build. My issue is that I want to create a list of parameters that is dependent on the first parameter. For example, My fist selection will be to choose a domain. I then want a list of parameters or services to populate below that correspond to the specific domain selected in the first parameter. The list of parameters will be different for each selected domain.

I have tried the Active Choice Parameter Plugin as well as the Active Reactive, however these only allow the choices of the parameter to be dynamic, not the actual list of parameters itself.

Is there another plugin I should look into?

Here is a link to another post which describes what I am trying to accomplish if what I stated above was unclear. This issue is still unresolved on the Jenkins site.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5914

Thank you!

Comment: My understanding is that you want a variable number of parameters for your job, and based on your previous selections some may appear or not. If I understood correctly, I don't think that's possible yet and probably your best choice is the Active Choice Parameter where you define all of them, but under certain setting some of them would have an ignorable value, eg `N/A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish the task above, I used the Active Choice Parameter to specify the first parameter selections. For the remaining parameters, I used the Avtice Choice Reactive Parameter which has a field to specify the parameter you wish to reference. this allows the parameter to re-fire every time you change the selection of the first parameter.